# Use a function from a module in another function Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a JavaScript module as follows in a file `draw.js`;

```
export default function Draw() {
      ...
      function Color () {}
      ...
}
```

And it contains the function `Color()` as shown in the code above.
Now I have separate module in the file `render.js` as shown below;

```
export default function Render() {
      ...
}
```

I will like to use the function `Color()` from `Draw()` in `Render()` without having to create it again. Is that possible and if yes, can anyone share how this can be achieved. Thanks

I wasn't quite able to find any help online in my searches so I decided to ask as there may be someone with more expert knowledge on this. Thanks!

Comment: does `Draw` return `Color`? If not, then move it to its own export.

Comment: Nested functions are not accessible outside the function that defines them. Usually the whole reason you nest it is to keep it from getting into the global scope.

Comment: Why is `Color` nested inside `Draw`?  Your example doesn't give any reason for it being like that.  If you can bump `Color` out one level of scope to make it a sibling of `Color` then you can use `export` without the `default` and export both `Draw` and `Color`.  and then `import { Draw, Color }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the scope abstraction and using 'Draw' variables/args, you can try using classes, something like:

```
class Draw {
 constructor(args){
  /* ... */ 
 }

 function color(){
  /* ... */ 
 } 
}

export default Draw;
```

so you would use like this:

```
import Draw from "./Draw";

export default function Render() {
      const draw = new Draw();
      const color = draw.color;
      // now 'color' is your function
}
```

Or as answered above, exporting 'Draw' and 'color'.